# Return value of an object from array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of object

```
const data = [{id:"1", "name":"ab", value:100, doubleval:'344'},{id:"2", "name":"ab", value:200,doubleval:'122'},{id:"1", "name":"bc", value:100, doubleval:'123'},{id:"1", "name":"bc", value:300, doubleval:'44'}]
```

so I want to get `value` from this So I tried using lodash

```
return _.filter(data, (item) => {
            return (item === 'ab') ? item?.value : budgetRangePlan?.doubleval
      })
```

This returns an  array of object,

here I was expecting value as 100 and 200 respectively.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Use `_.map()` or instead of `_.filter()`.

Comment: map returns an array of object as well.. I wanted to get the exact value

Answer (score 1):

Filter is for collect element fits a boolean condition.
For your code I think that you could try

```
let rs = data.map((data) => (data.name == 'ab' ? data.value : data.doubleval))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```js
const data = [{id:"1", "name":"ab", value:100, doubleval:'344'},{id:"2", "name":"ab", value:200,doubleval:'122'},{id:"1", "name":"bc", value:100, doubleval:'123'},{id:"1", "name":"bc", value:300, doubleval:'44'}]

let result = data.map(a => a.name == 'ab' ? a.value : a.doubleval);

console.log(result)
```

#### References

- [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Actually I want to return a single value for this

Comment: I edited the answer. Does it fix your problem now?

Comment: Forget that edit, it won't return a single value. I'm a bit confused...:D You want to return either the `value` 100 or 200 if `name` is `'ab'`?